# Tag Cloud with Background Shapes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, word-cloud

I search for a way to place shapes "behind" a tag in the popular and well known tag clouds, which would look like:

[image]

I like [wordcloud2.js](https://github.com/timdream/wordcloud2.js)... this script builds the tags with javascript and canvas-elements. As addition there shall be a shape or background image, so it looks like each tag has it own cloud.

Is this possible or does a different script for this already exist?

I also found a possibility, to generate [pseudo-clouds with CSS3](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/make-a-simple-cloud-in-css3). Maybe there is a way to combine them?

Comment: I took a way-too-quick look at your wordcloud2.js link. The user has the option to set the `backgroundColor`. Have you tried setting the backgroundColor to transparent alpha and then putting your cloud over your desired background image? This *may not work* because the wordcloud2JS code uses the backgroundColor to determine empty available space for new words. If that's the case, then you can use html5 canvas's `context.getImageData` after the cloud has been drawn and change the backgroundColor pixels to transparent.

Comment: @markE Thank you for the reply and the hints! Actually I'm not very good in js and css... it's more trial and error. I'm more familiar with php. I hope you understood it right, because a cloud-image instead of the backgroundColor will sourround the whole cloud, not a single tag, I guess. The author gave a suggestion to "drawing the cloud in a <div> and set some style to div > span". But as I said, that's too high for me. And there is another problem. The pseudo-cloud has no relative sizes, so it's complicated generate it that way without knowing the exact width/hight of each cloud-tag.